# Firestore Rule - limiting "list" access

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection on which I want to provide list access, but only in a limited manner for most users.

All users should be able to do this: (the string `valuex` can be anything)

```
collection("XYZ").where("fieldx", "==", "valuex").get()
```

Only admins can get all the documents:

```
collection("XYZ").get()
```

Note that as `valuex` can be anything, at the end of the day all users can see all documents. The difference is that non-admins need to know what to query, admins don't, they get it all directly.

The only solution I have found is to force non-admins to write to a document the value they are querying, prior to calling `get`. The rules then are:

```
allow list: if isadmin() || resource.data.fieldx == getvaluex();
function isadmin() { return request.auth.token.get("admin", false); }
function getvaluex() { return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid).data.valuex; }
```

That way all returned documents must have the same value for `fieldx`. But this solution 1) needs 1 additional write 2) adds a read in the rules and 3) in my case `valuex` is sensitive and I dont want the user to have to store it in Firestore.

So is there any better solution?

- Is it possible for instance to limit the usage of an index to only some users? (both queries above actually have more `where` statements and require each a specific composite index).
- Is it possible to compare the returned documents between each others to ensure they all have the same value for `fieldx`?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is this:

1. Don't allow non-admins to make those direct requests to the database at all.
2. Instead, have them send a request to a Firebase Http function.
3. The Http function has admin access to the db, it can accept any valuex *non-null* value.
4. It queries the db using that valuex, on behalf of the non-admin users, and returns the results.

This way, you can keep the documents in collection XYZ locked to non-admins in your Firestore Rules.

You can even keep sensitive data in those documents, since you have control on what you share with users. You can control that by choosing which fields your HTTP function will return to clients.

Mind you, Firebase function invocations are way cheaper than making additional writes/reads.

Comment: "Mind you, Firebase function invocations are way cheaper than making additional writes/reads."? Really? I thought it was the opposite

Comment: Reads/Writes are priced by 100K, Functions priced by 1M. Also, you get 2M free invocations per month.

Comment: @MarketerInCoderClothes When you access the Firestore data from the Cloud Function is also billed, so using cloud functions is more.

Comment: @Juancki It's cheaper in the OP's case, since he won't be using any Firestore Rules reads or any extra document writes like in the solution he was considering.

Comment: Unfortunately my app also has a several snapshots on this collection so users need to have some access to it

Comment: I have had this kind of debate with developers in my team. Firestore is designed to be access from client code. It is not a case of a 'database being exposed over the internet and therefore unsafe' In front of the document store (firestore) is a robust and scalable web socket application that has a sophisticated rules engine for security.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore works well for easy/normalized access from clients to collections and documents.

What you are trying to do is pretty specific to your implementation of the these "lists".

You may create another collection (list_auth) that tracks the accesses to the list.

In the security access you can create a security rule for the collection that looks up the permissions of `user` into the `list` by accessing the `list_auth` collection.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents